# Using @each to shorten @keyframe prefixes mixing in SCSS

Tags: sass, escaping, mixins, keyframe, string-interpolation

I'm trying to use a mixin to automatically prefix @keyframes

```
@mixin keyframePrefix($name) {
@-webkit-keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
}
@-moz-keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
}
@-o-keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
}
@keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
}
```

This technically works, but it's large. I have a prefixer mixin for individual properties that uses an @each statement to make this more compact:

```
$prefixes: ("-moz-", "-webkit-", "-o-", "");
@mixin prefix($property, $value) {
    @each $prefix in $prefixes {
        #{$prefix +  $property}: $value;
    }
}
```

However, my issue is with the string interpolation on the @-prefix-keyframes. It doesn't seem to want to let me just stick an @ in there:

```
@mixin keyframePrefix($name) {
    @each $prefix in $prefixes {
        @#{$prefix}keyframes #{$name} {
            @content;
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is: how can I escape the @ symbol? I've tried a lot of combinations of nesting interpolation and strings and whatnot, but nothing seems to work. Adding a backslash so the line reads `\@#{$prefix}keyframes #{$name}` is the closest I've gotten, and it compiles to `\@-moz-keyframes prompt 50%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpolation within name's directives is not allowed. You can find this [issue](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/429) opened. You have to use the large version until it is solved.

```
@mixin keyframes($name) {    
  @-webkit-keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
  }
  @-moz-keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
  }
  @-o-keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
  }
  @keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
  }
}
```

BTW, you were missing the final `}`.